# Linq group by and then get only one of the items

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have the following class which is used to assign tasks to employees.

```
public class TaskDetails
    {
        public int TaskGroupId { get; set; }
        public int TaskId { get; set; }
        public string AssignedTo { get; set; }
        public string TaskName { get; set; }

    }
```

Typically we get a list of task groups and who are they assigned to like the following, each task is grouped under **TaskGroupId** and under each group for each task we have a specific taskid and who is responsible for it.

```
List<TaskDetails> tasks = new List<TaskDetails>
            {
                new TaskDetails
                {
                    AssignedTo = "JOHN",
                    TaskGroupId = 100,
                    TaskId = 1,
                    TaskName = "FA"
                },
                new TaskDetails
                {
                    AssignedTo = "TOM",
                    TaskGroupId = 100,
                    TaskId = 1,
                    TaskName = "FA"
                },
                new TaskDetails
                {
                    AssignedTo = "JOHN",
                    TaskGroupId = 100,
                    TaskId = 2,
                    TaskName = "GH"
                },
                new TaskDetails
                {
                    AssignedTo = "TOM",
                    TaskGroupId = 100,
                    TaskId = 2,
                    TaskName = "GH"
                },
                new TaskDetails
                {
                    AssignedTo = "JOHN",
                    TaskGroupId = 99,
                    TaskId = 1,
                    TaskName = "XY"
                },
                new TaskDetails
                {
                    AssignedTo = "TOM",
                    TaskGroupId = 99,
                    TaskId = 1,
                    TaskName = "XY"
                },
                new TaskDetails
                {
                    AssignedTo = "JOHN",
                    TaskGroupId = 99,
                    TaskId = 2,
                    TaskName = "YX"
                },
                new TaskDetails
                {
                    AssignedTo = "TOM",
                    TaskGroupId = 99,
                    TaskId = 2,
                    TaskName = "YX"
                }
            };
```

What I am trying to do is to group each task by **TaskGroupId** and **AssignedTo**, however if a task is assigned to more than one person I only need to retrieve one of them back, in the above example, task 1 is assigned to John and Tom but I only need one of them, it does not matter which one (it could be Tom or John). I have tried the following but it is retrieving 4 results and both John and Tom as seen in the screenshot. I could remove the x.AssignedTo from the GroupBy statement which gives me  2 results but then the tasks are then repeated in TaskLegs section, so not useful either.

[image]

```
 var result = tasks
   .GroupBy(x => new { 
      x.TaskGroupId, 
      x.AssignedTo })
   .Select(group => new { 
      GroupDetails = group.Key, 
      TaskLegs = group
        .OrderBy(x => x.TaskId)
        .ToList() })
   .ToList();
```

Is there anyway of grouping the results in a way so I can only retrieve one of the results from the grouped resultset? Based on the above example I am trying to get 2 results, one for task group 100 and one for task group 99.

Thanks

Comment: If only there were a `.First()` extension method...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want one item per `TaskGroupId` then you only group by that field. Grouping by `TaskGroupId` and `AssignedTo` means that you will get one group for each combination of the two which is why you are getting four items.

So your query must start:

```
tasks.GroupBy (x => x.TaskGroupId)
```

You then have two groups (for TaskGroupId 99 and 100).

You then need to select the data into the form you want. I'm a little unclear on what form this data should take. Should it just have one task under each group?
 If so something like:

```
.Select(group => new { TaskGroupId = group.Key, TaskLegs = group.OrderBy(x => x.TaskId).First() }).
```

If it should have each distinct task in there then you will need to do some more grouping:

```
.Select(group => new { 
    TaskGroupId  = group.Key, 
    TaskLegs = group
        .GroupBy(x=>x.TaskId)
        .Select(y => y.First())
        .OrderBy(y=>y.TaskId) 
})
```

This will give you two items, one for each taskgroup. Each of those items will have two items in the TaskLegs, for TaskIds 1 and 2.

**Bonus thought:**

If you wanted to list all people assigned to a task you could change your definition of TaskLegs to:

```
TaskLegs = group
    .GroupBy(x=>x.TaskId)
    .Select(y => new {
        TaskId = y.Key, 
        AssignedTo = y.Select(z => z.AssignedTo)
    })
    .OrderBy(y=>y.TaskId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
var result = tasks.GroupBy(x => new x.TaskGroupId) .Select(group => new { GroupDetails = group.Key, TaskLegs = group.Take(1) }) .ToList();
```